# As a former Nigerian citizen, can I travel visa free with my current Spanish passport?

Tags: visas, spain, spanish-citizens, nigeria

I have had this question for a LONG time. I acquired Spanish citizenship 6 years ago; I'm originally from Nigeria. Every time I want to travel to Nigeria the same question comes up: Can I travel to Nigeria on my valid Spanish passport together with my EXPIRED Nigerian passport and go visa-free? This will be the 4th time I'll be paying for a visa I'm never really sure I need?

Any backed up information would be REALLY appreciated!!!!

Comment: Did you actually renounce your Nigerian citizenship?

Comment: @MJeffryes Spain requires naturalized citizens to renounce the other citizenship unless the other citizenship is from a short list of countries which Nigeria is not on.

Comment: Why do you describe yourself as "a former Nigerian citizen?"

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica because OP renounced their Nigerian citizenship whilst acquiring the Spanish one. Hence, a former Nigerian citizen.

Answer (score 10):

Former nationals of Nigeria can enter Nigeria visa-free by traveling with their new passport of their new nationality along with their expired Nigerian passport.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
>
> Visa required, except for Former nationals of Nigeria with a
>   valid foreign passport and an expired Nigerian passport.